# Javascript click function issue

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem with my js. Once the page loads it fires logTest and not every time I click.

```
function logTest() {
 console.log('test');
}

var id = document.querySelector('#id');
id.addEventListener("click", logTest(), false);
```

Comment: You should not use parenthesis, this executes the function call instead of passing in the function as an argument. Try: `id.addEventListener("click", logTest, false);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is good except the parenthesis after you bind logTest to the click event. Parenthesis invoking the function immediately, and not binding it to the event.

```
id.addEventListener("click", logTest, false);
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to bind the event to the function itself, not to its return value. Remove the `()` after `logTest` when you're adding the event listener:

```
id.addEventListener("click", logTest, false);
```

You could use [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) instead of `querySelector`, and also note, for IE < 9, you need to use [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead. A work around can be found in [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

I'd suggest something like this:

```
var id = document.getElementById('id');
if (id.addEventListener) {
    id.addEventListener("click", logTest, false); 
} else if (id.attachEvent)  {
    id.attachEvent("click", logTest);
}
```

If you happen to be using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), this can be simplified to:

```
$('#id').click(logTest);
```

Comment: Downvoters, care to comment? If there is anything wrong in my answer, I'd be glad to correct it.